# Elegant way to signify inheritance and relationship between posts

Tags: media, child-pages, design

Let's say I have a weekly podcast, that I use WordPress as my CMS, and that I use LibSyn to host my media.

This podcast is one hour long, and includes several "special" content segments that I also want to upload as *individual* files. So for this week's show, for example, I want the following media to be available to listeners/web-visitors:

1. The complete show
2. The "Y" segment from said complete show
3. The "X" segment from said complete show

Now, I want a way for visitors to be able to relate between those "child" segments and their "parent" show, and vice versa.

I don't have *that much* experience with PHP, but I've been using WordPress for 10 years and know its core concepts.

So right now I can only think of this *not-very-smart* workaround:

Each complete show and each individual segment will get their own post. There will be two post formats, with one of those formats, "standard", styled with a bigger headings (for complete show posts) than the other (individual segments).

So for this week's show, a visitor will see something like this on the WordPress homepage:

## Complete Show for 06/11/14

[Short Description for Show]

[WEB PLAYER HERE]

Separate Segments:

- [Href link to Segment "X" Here]
- [Href link to Segment "Y" Here]

#### Segment "X" from 06/11/14 Show

[Short Description for Segment "X"]

[WEB PLAYER HERE]

[Href link to Parent show, which is the previous post titled "Complete Show for 06/11/14"]

#### Segment "Y" from 06/11/14 Show

[Short Description for Segment "Y"]

[WEB PLAYER HERE]

[Href link to Parent show, which is the previous post titled "Complete Show for 06/11/14"]

---

So yeah, this *should* work. But it looks to me there's gotta be a better way to go about with this. I thought about #NAME HTML tags in one post with several players, but the problem with this is that posts won't have their own permalinks if for example someone wants to share an individual segments on Twitter or FB.

Any advice is appreciated.

Comment: I think its much easier to use custom fields to store the segments. The best plugin to use is Advanced Custom Fields PRO(or buy the separate Repeater addon), or you can use the free alternative called Simple Fields and look for also the repeater function.

Comment: Thanks, but how does ACF help here using my example of 1 complete show and 2 original segments that belong to it originally?

Comment: Why dont you try using the post to post plugin api for doing post relationshio 1 * 1 1*many many*many.

Comment: Thanks @TTechITSolutions -- I did take a look at Post 2 Post but I didn't really understand how exactly it works, to me it seems like it automatically detects relationships by tag. Additioally, development for this plugin has been suspended.

Comment: Check my answer below, it may clear some bits up about posts 2 posts

Comment: If i understand your question correctly, the 2 segments are a part if the complete show and you can only access the complete show from the frontend right? When you click on it, on the same page it will show the 2 additional segments. So if this is the case then you really don't need to create new posts for the segments.

Comment: No. Individual segments have to have their own permalink so they have to be separate posts.

Answer (score 0):

Using the Posts 2 Posts Module which is still being developed just no support is being offered except through the git fork.  How to use it.

```
function my_connection_types() {
    p2p_register_connection_type( array(
        'name' => 'posts_to_pages',
        'from' => 'post_type_1',
        'to' => 'post_type_2',
        'cardinality' => 'one-to-many'
    ) );
}
add_action( 'p2p_init', 'my_connection_types' );
```

The above example will create a 1 to many relationship a post from post type 1 is in a relationship with many posts from post_type_2.  Change carnality where needed. You will then have a metabox in your posts to add the relationships.

```
<?php
// Find connected pages
$connected = new WP_Query( array(
  'connected_type' => 'posts_to_pages',
  'connected_items' => get_queried_object(),
  'nopaging' => true,
) );

// Display connected pages
if ( $connected->have_posts() ) :
?>
<h3>Related pages:</h3>
<ul>
<?php while ( $connected->have_posts() ) : $connected->the_post(); ?>
    <li><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></li>
<?php endwhile; ?>
</ul>

<?php 
// Prevent weirdness
wp_reset_postdata();

endif;
?>
```

The above snippet if run on a single.php template will show the pages that the current post is connected with.